# What is the correct JQL query if I want to search all projects of a particular jira user?

Tags: jira, jql

I tried the JQL query below but it does not work.

project is EMPTY AND assignee = johndew

The output I want is a list of projects of the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jira users are not directly connected to Projects. They are working / assigned to Jira issues, which belong to a Project.

It can not expressed in just a JQL. But when creating an issue filter with JQL like `assignee = johndew` and then save it, like 'issues-johndew'. Then open one of the Jira Dashboards and add the Gadget *Issue Statstics*. Fill in the field *Project or Saved Filter* the value of the filter `issues-johndew`. Fill in the field Static Type **Project**.

This should give an overview of where John Dew is working on.

*In Jira this is the shown as below*

[image: Issues per Assignee]

Comment: @BreinnAguilar in case the answer is good enough, can you accept it? Thx

Comment: Thank you I understand this. I will try and give feedback.

Comment: This procedure works PERFECTLY! Thank you so much! ;)

Comment: @BreinnAguilar Nice :) Thx for the feedback!